# MongoDB fails to respond on localhost but works for another node app

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm working on a new node.js app on an old server I use for dev stuff.

Both apps have the mongo URL specified:

```
var mongoUri = 'mongodb://localhost/node';
```

but on startup, the old node.js app works fine, but the new one doesn't. The new one returns the following for `node server.js`

```
Error: unable to connect to database at mongodb://localhost/node
    at NativeConnection.<anonymous> (/var/www/server/server.js:15:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at NativeConnection.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at /var/www/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:336:19
    at args.push (/var/www/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:403:25)
    at /var/www/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:254:21
    at connectCallback (/var/www/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:933:5)
    at /var/www/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:782:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be really appreciated. I've tried everything short of reinstalling mongo at this point :(

Comment: You need to include port number in URI

Comment: Duh. Thanks man. I guess the other one must be running on and older version of the npm module